# Socket Programming - Simple Client/Server Application

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I've have this code here of a simple Client/Server application.
How it works: The client enters "get time", and the server responds with the time.

The problem is that a NullReferenceException is thrown after the client successfully connects to the server. Why does that happen?

Codes:

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Time_Client
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Client";
            LoopConnect();
            SendLoop();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void SendLoop()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a request: ");
                string req = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
                clientSocket.Send(buffer);
                byte[] receivedBuf = new byte[1024];
                int rec = clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuf);
                byte[] data = new byte[rec];
                Array.Copy(receivedBuf, data, rec);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
            }
        }
        private static void LoopConnect()
        {
            int attempts = 0;
            while (!clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    attempts++;
                    clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 100);
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection attempts: " + attempts);
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Time_Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        private static List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100));
            serverSocket.Listen(5);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), null);
        }
        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            clientSockets.Add(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), socket);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }
        private static void RecieveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received = socket.EndReceive(AR); // the exception is thrown here
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, dataBuf, received);

            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("Text received: " + text);
            string response = "";
            if (text.ToLower() != "get time")
            {
                response = "Invalid Request";
            }
            else
            {
                response = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), socket);
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), socket);
        }
        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is the exception thrown - the client or the server? (And have you considered using `TcpClient` and `TcpListener`?)

Comment: The exception is thrown at the Server. Honestly, I've copied the code off a YouTube video (since I'm new to the subject), but for some reason it works on the YouTube video but not here. What is the problem?

Comment: I very much doubt that the code works *as is*, given the problem I've identified in my answer... (It's also not great code in terms of its use of static variables etc... I think you'd be better off finding examples on MSDN if you can.)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ah, I was mistaken in what was wrong. This is the problem.

```
serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), null);
```

Note that you're using `RecieveCallback` instead of `AcceptCallback`. So you end up in `RecieveCallback` (which should be `ReceiveCallback`, by the way) at which point you find the async state - which is null - and call `EndReceive`... but this isn't the callback for `Receive` operation, it's a callback for an `Accept` operation.

The line above should be:

```
serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
```

However, if you're trying to write a *simple* client/server program, I would avoid using async IO at all, and just go for synchronous operations, to start with. When you *do* want to use asynchronous operations, use `async` / `await` from C# 5 - it'll make your life a lot easier.

I'd also recommend using the [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) and [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) classes to make things simpler. They're wrappers around the sockets.

Comment: Thanks, but now it throws a new exception: "The IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding asynchronous method on this class.
Parameter name: asyncResult"

Comment: @BlueRay010: Ah - you've also got the wrong callback. Editing.

Comment: OK, Thank you. Edited the code as you said, but now there's a tiny problem. When I say "get time" for example, it writes in the server "Text received" a lot of times instead of one. And when I enter an invalid request, it writes in the client a lot of "Invalid Request" instead of just once. How can I fix that?

Comment: @BlueRay010: Those sound like separate questions. Stack Overflow really isn't a good way of handling this sort of thing, where you've started off with a bunch of code you don't really understand - it's better when there's a single distinct problem. I suggest you spend some time working through the problems, diagnosing them as best you can, and then ask a new question if necessary. I'd also *strongly* recommend using synchronous code unless the whole point of the exercise is to learn about asynchronous socket programming. It'll be *much* simpler to see what's going on synchronously.

Comment: I know, I'm trying to learn, but I don't really understand why this happens. What is the reason for this writing so much times "Invalid Request" for example? I'm trying to learn, this is part of it. So why not just once? Where's the problem?

Comment: @BlueRay010: You've missed my point - that's a separate problem, and if I help you fix that one are you going to ask another one in the same comment thread? That's really not the way that Stack Overflow is meant to be used. Put in some work to try to find the answer for yourself, then ask a new question.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that there aren't really good places to learn C# socket programming at (only YouTube videos are the actual good place to learn). Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @BlueRay010: I wouldn't start with videos, personally. I'd start with the examples in MSDN, and *not* start with asynchronous code.

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot. In the past hour I've seen some examples for synchronous sockets on MSDN and I'm now understanding how it all works. Gotta say though, that Asynchronous Sockets are extremely hard compared to Synchronous Sockets...

Comment: @BlueRay010: Yup, asynchrony is a pain in general. Which is why C# 5 has it baked into the language to make it simpler :)